# Compressing const wchar_t strings in program memory

Tags: c, unicode, avr

I am building an avr program with many wchar_t strings. At the moment the way I store them in to the chip is this:

```
const _flash wchar_t* const  Greek_text[] =
{
    [ACCELERATION_TEXT] = (const _flash wchar_t[]) {L"Επιταγχυνση"},
    [ACCELERATION_SHORT_TEXT] = (const _flash wchar_t[]) {L"Επιταγχ."},
    [REDUCED_TEXT] = (const _flash wchar_t[]) {L"Μειωμενη"},
    [FULL_TEXT] = (const _flash wchar_t[]) {L"Μεγιστη"}
}
```

I am looking for a way to store them while being compressed. One way that I can think of, is removing the Unicode prefix for the specific language, but the only way of doing this to my knowledge, is storing the lower half of each word manually in unsigned chars. Is there a more practical way of doing something like this?

Comment: Why did you tag this "stm32"?

Comment: Is an actual widespread compression algorithm on the table? As opposed to writing your own compression that will be error prone and less space and compute efficient?

Comment: Might see if you can get [BOCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Ordered_Compression_for_Unicode) or [SCSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Compression_Scheme_for_Unicode) working on the system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all your strings are Greek.  You could assign each letter or character that appears in your strings to a number between 1 and 255 and then just have `char` strings where each `char` contains one of those encoded numbers.  This would halve the space of each individual string, but you might need a lookup table in your program to convert those codes back to unicode, and that table could occupy up to 512 bytes in your program memory depending on how many different characters you use.

People have already developed encodings like this before, so maybe you could just use a standard one, like [Windows-1253](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253).

Figuring out a good system to author these encoded strings and insert them into your program is another challenge.  I'd suggest writing a simple Ruby program like the one below.  (You'd save the program itself as a UTF-8 text file on your computer and edit it using a standard text editor.)

```rb
string_table = {
  ACCELERATION_TEXT: 'Επιταγχυνση',
  ACCELERATION_SHORT_TEXT: 'Επιταγχ.',
  REDUCED_TEXT: 'Μειωμενη',
  FULL_TEXT: 'Μεγιστη',
}

string_table.each do |key, value|
  hex = value.encode('Windows-1253').each_byte.map { |b| '\x%02x' % b }.join
  puts "[#{key}] = \"#{hex}\","
end
```

The program above outputs this:

```c
[ACCELERATION_TEXT] = "\xc5\xf0\xe9\xf4\xe1\xe3\xf7\xf5\xed\xf3\xe7",
[ACCELERATION_SHORT_TEXT] = "\xc5\xf0\xe9\xf4\xe1\xe3\xf7\x2e",
[REDUCED_TEXT] = "\xcc\xe5\xe9\xf9\xec\xe5\xed\xe7",
[FULL_TEXT] = "\xcc\xe5\xe3\xe9\xf3\xf4\xe7",
```

Also, another way to maybe save space (while increasing CPU time used) would be to get rid of the array of pointers you are creating.  This would save two bytes per string.  Just store all the strings next to each other in memory.  The strings would be separated by null characters and you can optionally have a double null character marking the end of the table.  To look up a string in the table, you start reading bytes from the beginning of the table one at a time and count how many null characters you have seen.

```c
const _flash char greek_text[] =
   "\xc5\xf0\xe9\xf4\xe1\xe3\xf7\xf5\xed\xf3\xe7\0"
   "\xc5\xf0\xe9\xf4\xe1\xe3\xf7\x2e\0"
   "\xcc\xe5\xe9\xf9\xec\xe5\xed\xe7\0"
   "\xcc\xe5\xe3\xe9\xf3\xf4\xe7\0";
```

Comment: A much better way to do the latter is Pascal strings, storing them as a buffer like "<len0><str0><len1><str1>...". This way you can just skip strings quickly, without having to parse every single character until you reach your string.

Comment: How do you figure? Skipping a string goes from O(n) to O(1) and the space used is the same (byte length instead of null separator).

Comment: *Also, another way to save space (while increasing CPU time used) ...*  if space saving is critical, the extra code needed to process compressed data will also take up more space.

Comment: Yes, it's up to the OP to try these things out and see which techniques actually save the most space, since that depends on how much string data there is and how well the compiler can optimize the extra code.